# DBeaver: How to export a result without running 2 queries

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I have a query that takes 3-5 minutes to run, so I'd rather not run the query once to generate the result set, and then a second time to generate the exported .csv file. Is there any way to only run the query once in DBeaver? Bonus if I get to visualize the output in DBeaver and then generate the .csv after without rerunning the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Right now if you want to export the result set to a .csv, you need to rerun the query. However, a nice workaround is to first run the query on a subset (time, users, LIMIT, etc.) and once it's good, you can directly export results to a .csv by doing the following in the editor:

right click > Execute > Export From Query.

Answer (score 9):

In recent versions of DBeaver you can simply highlight the SQL code that you want to run (in the editor), then right click the highlighted SQL code > Execute > Export From Query. 
The step of having to run the query first is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Database tasks.
Create new task, select Data Export, enter your query and every time you run your task, the export will be created in a folder you have been selected.
Or start export from a grid, then click Save task when you get to the Output tab.
Then you can change your task to have similar queries executed and data exported in one click, when task is run again.